# Invalid column warning with EFCore that I cant figure out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am going through the following pluralsite tutorial (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/asp-dot-net-core-restful-api-building/table-of-contents) 
and trying to apply the knowledge to an existing database I have at the same time as making the base application.

1) I place a break point at the beginning of AddAsset in AssetRepository.

2) I send the following POST request to my API:

```
POST http://localhost:6059/api/assets

{
    "bay": "X",
    "tile":  "1",
    "Serialnumber": "SERIAL",
    "devicename": "DEVICENAME",
    "assetspecs" : [
            {
                "assetattrid": "SIZE",
                "numvalue":12
            },
            {
                "assetattrid": "POWER",
                "numvalue":24
            }
        ]
}
```

3) CreateAsset is ran from AssetController and AddAsset runs from the repository through the controller

4) The debugger comes across the line _assetRepository.AddAsset(assetEntity);  and runs AddAsset from the repository

5) Right before the last line of AssetRepository.AddAsset is executed, (_context.Asset.Add(asset);) the debugger shows me that I have a properly formed set of records with unique ids prior to entering the line - everything looks ok and like it should be added to the db.

6) I hit f11 and the debugger jumps into my context file and runs through OnConfiguring and OnModelCreating with no issues then back into the CreateAsset 
controller action where it left off.

7) I hit f11 AGAIN and the if (!_assetRepository.Save()) condition is checked which throws an acception telling me I have an invalid column name Assetuid. In the application insights debugging output the column is capitalized and all other columns start with a lowercase which seemed odd.

I've spent a half a day on this and am at a loss if anyone can help. There are a few more files that might be involved that I didnt represent, if you need to see anything further, please let me know and thank you!!!!

aContext.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace AssetAPI.Entities
{
    public partial class aContext : DbContext
    {
        public aContext(DbContextOptions<aContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public static IConfiguration Configuration;

        public virtual DbSet<Asset> Asset { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Assetspec> Assetspec { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["connectionStrings:AssetDBConnectionString"])
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }
            else
            {
                optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Assetuid)
                    .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);

                     entity.ToTable("asset");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Assetid)
                    .HasName("asset_indx7");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Assetuid)
                    .HasName("asset_ndx")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Barcode)
                    .HasName("asset_barcode");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Pluscphyloc)
                    .HasName("asset_ndx16");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Status)
                    .HasName("asset_ndx15");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetnum, e.Assetuid })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx17");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetnum, e.Siteid })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx11")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetnum, e.Status })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx8");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Orgid, e.Status })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx13");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Ancestor })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx7");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Assetnum })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx1")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .ForSqlServerIsClustered();

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Calnum })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx4");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Location })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx6");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Parent })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx2");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Status })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx10");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Vendor })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx3");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetid, e.Siteid, e.Moved })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx14")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetnum, e.Location, e.Siteid })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx12");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Itemnum, e.Siteid, e.Itemsetid })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx5");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Siteid, e.Location, e.Parent })
                    .HasName("asset_ndx9");

                entity.Property(e => e.Assetuid)
                    .HasColumnName("assetuid");
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

              ..... Properties hidden, lots of them, came from scaffolding existing table

            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Assetspec>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("assetspec");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Assetspecid)
                    .HasName("assetspec_ndx")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetattrid, e.Section })
                    .HasName("assetspec_ndx3");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetnum, e.Siteid })
                    .HasName("assetspec_ndx4");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Classstructureid, e.Assetattrid, e.Section })
                    .HasName("assetspec_ndx2");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Assetattrid, e.Assetnum, e.Section, e.Siteid, e.Linearassetspecid })
                    .HasName("assetspec_ndx1")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.Assetspecid)
                    .HasColumnName("assetspecid")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

                ...   ..... Properties hidden, lots of them, came from scaffolding existing table
            });
        }
    }
}
```

AssetRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AssetAPI.Entities;

namespace AssetAPI.Services
{
    public class AssetRepository : IAssetRepository
    {
        private aContext _context;

        public AssetRepository(aContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void AddAsset(Entities.Asset asset)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            asset.Assetid = rnd.Next(20000000, 30000000);
            asset.Assetuid = rnd.Next(20000000, 30000000);
            asset.Assetnum = rnd.Next(800000, 900000).ToString();
            asset.Barcode = asset.Assetnum;
            asset.Changedate = DateTime.Now;
            asset.Changeby = "123";
            asset.Langcode = "EN";
            asset.Siteid = "SITE";
            asset.Orgid = "ORG";



            // the repository fills the id (instead of using identity columns)
            if (asset.Assetspecs.Any())
            {
                foreach (var assetspec in asset.Assetspecs)
                {
                    Random rnd2 = new Random();

                    assetspec.Assetspecid = rnd2.Next(20000000, 30000000);
                    assetspec.Changedate = DateTime.Today;
                    assetspec.Assetnum = asset.Assetnum;
                    assetspec.Classstructureid = "1140";
                    assetspec.Orgid = "ORG";
                    assetspec.Siteid = "SITE";
                    assetspec.Continuous = 0;
                    assetspec.Displaysequence = 0;
                    assetspec.Inheritedfromitem = 0;
                    assetspec.Itemspecvalchanged = 0;
                    assetspec.Mandatory = 0;

                 }
            }



            _context.Asset.Add(asset);



        }

        public void AddAssetspecForAsset(string assetnum, Assetspec assetspec)
        {
            var asset = GetAsset(assetnum);
            if (asset != null)
            {
                assetspec.Assetnum = assetnum;
                assetspec.Changeby = "123";
                assetspec.Changedate = DateTime.Now;
                assetspec.Classstructureid = "1140";
                assetspec.Orgid = "ORG";
                assetspec.Siteid = "SITE";

                // if there isn't an id filled out (ie: we're not upserting),
                // we should generate one
                if (assetspec == null)
                {
                    Random rnd2 = new Random();

                    assetspec.Assetspecid = rnd2.Next(20000000, 30000000);
                    assetspec.Assetattrid = "RUSZ";
                    assetspec.Numvalue = 12;
                }
                asset.Assetspecs.Add(assetspec);
            }
        }

        public bool AssetExists(string assetnum)
        {
            return _context.Asset.Any(a => a.Assetnum == assetnum);
        }


        public Asset GetAsset(string assetnum)
        {
            return _context.Asset.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Assetnum == assetnum);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Entities.Asset> GetAssets()
        {
            // return _context.Asset.OrderBy(a => a.Barcode).ThenBy(a => a.Bay).ThenBy(a => a.Tile).Take(10).ToList();
            return _context.Asset.OrderByDescending(a => a.Bay).ThenBy(a => a.Tile).Take(10).ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Entities.Asset> GetAssets(IEnumerable<string> Assetnums)
        {
            return _context.Asset.Where(a => Assetnums.Contains(a.Assetnum))
                .OrderBy(a => a.Barcode)
                .OrderBy(a => a.Bay)
                .OrderBy(a => a.Tile)
                .ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Assetspec> GetAssetspecsForAsset(string assetnum)
        {
            return _context.Assetspec
                        .Where(b => b.Assetnum == assetnum && b.Assetattrid == "RUSZ").OrderBy(b => b.Assetnum).ToList();
        }


        public bool Save()
        {
            return (_context.SaveChanges() >= 0);
        }

        public Assetspec GetAssetspecsForAsset(string assetnum, long assetspecId)
        {
            return _context.Assetspec
                          .Where(b => b.Assetnum == assetnum && b.Assetspecid == assetspecId).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Asset.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AssetAPI.Entities
{
    public partial class Asset
    {


        [Key]
        public long Assetuid { get; set; }
        public string Bay { get; set; }
        public string Tile { get; set; }
        public string TileLocation { get; set; }
        public string Serialnumber { get; set; }
        public string Devicename { get; set; }

           ....scaffolded properties hidden

        public  virtual ICollection<Assetspec> Assetspecs { get; set; } = new List<Assetspec>();
    }
}
```

AssetsController.cs

```
using AssetAPI.Models;
using AssetAPI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using AssetAPI.Entities;

namespace AssetAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/assets")]
    public class AssetsController : Controller
        {
            private IAssetRepository _assetRepository;

        public AssetsController(IAssetRepository assetRepository)
        {
            _assetRepository = assetRepository;
        }
        public IActionResult GetAssets()
        {
            var assetsFromRepo = _assetRepository.GetAssets();

            var assets = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AssetDTO>>(assetsFromRepo);

            return Ok(assets);
        }

        [HttpGet("{assetnum}", Name = "GetAsset")]
        public IActionResult GetAsset(string assetnum)
        {
            var assetFromRepo = _assetRepository.GetAsset(assetnum); //Run GetAsset method for the passed in Assetid from AssetRepository

            if (assetFromRepo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var asset = Mapper.Map<AssetDTO>(assetFromRepo); //Map the entity to the DTO
            return Ok(asset); //Return the result in JSON format
        }


        //[FromBody] attribute signifies that parameter should be serialized from the request body into AssetForCreationDTO
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateAsset([FromBody] AssetForCreationDTO asset)
        {
            //If the input provider in the request body was correctly serialized to an AssetForCreationDTO
            if (asset == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var assetEntity = Mapper.Map<Asset>(asset); //Map the entity to the DTO

            _assetRepository.AddAsset(assetEntity); //Add the entity to the DBContext

            if (!_assetRepository.Save()) //If the new resource cannot be saved
            {
                throw new Exception("Creating asset failed upon save");
                return StatusCode(500, "A problem occured.");
            }

            //Map the results again to learn the ID of the newly created resource
            var assetToReturn = Mapper.Map<AssetDTO>(assetEntity);

            //In case of a successful post, return 201 created response with location header
            //First param = name of route
            //Second = anon type containing new resource id
            //Third = Response body of newly created resource
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetAsset", new { assetnum =  assetToReturn.assetnum }, assetToReturn);
        }


    }
}
```

AssetDTO.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AssetAPI.Models
{
    public class AssetDTO
    {

        public string assetnum { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string Bay { get; set; }
        public string Tile { get; set; }
        public string TileLocation { get; set; }
        public string Serialnumber { get; set; }
        public string Devicename { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AssetForCreationDTO:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AssetAPI.Models
{
    public class AssetForCreationDTO
    {
        public string Bay { get; set; }
        public string Tile { get; set; }
        public string TileLocation { get; set; }
        public string Serialnumber { get; set; }
        public string Devicename { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AssetspecForCreationDTO> Assetspecs { get; set; } = new List<AssetspecForCreationDTO>();
    }
}
```

Comment: after closer inspection of debug output, I see that assetuid is being added as a column to the assetspec entity. Not sure why, but im going to look into that and try to answer my own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem.

I was not enforcing a relationship the way EFcore wants it due to the way the application behind this code uses tables and I had ASSETUID incorrectly set as the key field.

Since the assetspec entity doesnt have an ASSETUID column, this causes problems with navigation properties according to some research I did.

I changed the PK to ASSETNUM; since both entities have ASSETNUM as a property, im all good now!